# Need help port forwarding inside Hyper V for multiple servers

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, hyper-v, gaming

So my conundrum is, I have a WinServer 22 Datacenter host with a WinServer 22 Standard nested inside of it through Hyper-V.

My issue is that I have two game servers running on this one VM server and my primary game server is running as intended on ports 7777, 7778, 27015, and 32330 for RCON, all UDP. But I have a secondary server running on ports 7779, 7780, 27016, 32331 for RCON, all UDP; and it refuses to show up. I currently have it setup with one External Virtual Ethernet Switch and then two Virtual NICs for the one nested server with separate IPs and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

I have forwarded all ports in both the nested server and the host server and my Google Wifi settings to no avail.

Any help would be most appreciated.

EDIT: Not sure what fixed it but its working now, thanks to Ramhound for attempting to help me; you were great bro.

Comment: Assume the intranet IP address of the server and VM are different?

Comment: Yes, by 1 digit (if that makes any difference)

Comment: Are you forwarding the traffic on those ports to the host or the VM?

Comment: @Ramhound - I am attempting to forward directly to the VM but that didnt work for server 2 as it doesnt show up in the list of available IPs/MACs. So then I attempted to forward through the Host to the VM but that failed as well.

Comment: "show up in the list of available IPs/MACs." - Where? Are you perhaps behind double nat?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, the list of assignable IPs/MACs in my gateway which is a Google Wifi node. Im not sure how I would check for double NAT.

Comment: Is your Google WiFi assigned a internet or a intranet IP address?  Do you have to assign IP addresses from a static list? Why isn't those node using DHCP? Are these IP address intranet or internet IP addresses?

Comment: I mean, as far as I am aware everything on the LAN side of my modem should be intranet, unless I misunderstand? And my Wifi node is assigning IPs with DHCP. But that being said I have manually assigned IPs for all of my networking equipment and my servers.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of this "selection of IP addresses" assuming they are indeed intranet IP addresses and not internet IP addresses?  I am unfamiliar with Google WiFi and how the service works, but how a modem works is practically universal.  You typically don't "select" an address from a list.  You might type in the address, or the address might indeed be a list, but it contains every device being managed by it's DHCP service.

Comment: Im not sure im comfortable putting that info on here, im not sure if or how it could be used against me; it is a device list using local IP 192.168.xxx.xxx addresses, so they should all be intranet afaik. The issue I have is the IP that is assigned to my secondary NIC on my first VM on my host, does not show, only the IP of the primary NIC. Im not even sure if I need to have a second NIC honestly, BUT I tried routing all my traffic for my secondary game server through the primary NIC and it still wouldnt show up correctly.

I can share a drawing of my network topology if that helps...

Comment: Your not comfortable putting IP addresses that only exist within your own network?  I am asking for a screenshot that has been cropped to only provide the information I requested. You indicated your modem is using DHCP, which means devices connected to it, are receiving IP addresses that only exist within your own network. My computer is assigned `192.168.0.66` and `192.168.0.70`

Comment: Easy killer, im not sure what info is ok to give out and what isnt, im new to this level of networking...

Ok, I dont know what hcanged overnight, but now I can see my other vNIC and my other VM, let me see if I can route to them and I will update...

https://imgur.com/CxXD40Q

Comment: Yeah, idk why but now I can see all the IPs I was missing for the vNICs for the VRising server and BOTH ARK vNICs. Sorry to have wasted everyones time....